# how to get the selected range address in the form of a string value

Tags: cells

I am writing a simple macro where I have selected a range by using `EndDownArrow` and now want the VB to give me back the selected range. Can anyone please help?

**My codes so far are:-**

```
Range("B4:C4").Select 
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

Comment: i need VB to give me the selected range in a string value

Comment: btw, B4 and c4 contains my data header and below it there can be data upto any row. By doing xldown arrow, I am dynamically selecting the full data range. I need VB to tell me the range it selected e.g. B4:C10000

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub G()
    Dim rng As Range
    With Range("B4:C4")
        Set rng = Range(.Cells, .End(xlDown))
    End With
End Sub
```